# Cannot Pass Data between <test> tags in testng suite

Tags: java, testng, listener

I am working with a TestNG xml file like the one copied at the bottom of this post.  In order to parameterize the tests by browser, I have broken down each class into a separate  node.

As part of our integration with our reporting software, we store a piece of data provided by each test method in an arraylist that is handled by the ITestContext object.  In the @afterSuite method, that objects uploads that information to our reporting software

In other suites, where the classes all exist in the same  node this works fine.  However, in this suite, we only get data for the very last  node.  It appears to be overwriting the previous three by creating a new instance of ITestContext with each .  Unfortunately I cannot consolidate this suite into a singe  because we will lose the ability to parameterize the tests.

I need to know if there is an accepted way to pass information between test methods contained in different  nodes.  I've tried using static variables in the common parent (unsuccessfully), and can't find anything in the testNG docs about setting a global variable.

```
<suite name="UL" parallel="tests" thread-count="1" verbose="10">
    <parameter name="env" value="jobcaseStaging6"/>
    <parameter name="recordTests" value="1"/>
    <listeners>
    </listeners>
    <test name="UL Tests firefox">
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.selenium_tests.ULTests">
                <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="UL Tests chrome">
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.selenium_tests.ULTests">
                <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="UL Tests safari">
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.selenium_tests.ULTests">
                <parameter name="browser" value="bs_safari"/>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="UL Tests edge">
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.selenium_tests.ULTests">
                <parameter name="browser" value="bs_edge"/>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically there are two scenarios here and for each of the scenario TestNG provides a proper way of sharing data:

1. All the test classes (A test class is a class that houses one or more `@Test` methods) reside in the same `<test>` tag and would like to share data amongst themselves.

In this scenario you should make use of the `ITestContext` object and share data via attributes of the `ITestContext` object.

2. The test classes reside in one or more `<test>` tag and would like to share data amongst themselves.

In this scenario you should make use of the `ISuite` object and share data via attributes of the `ITestContext` object.

Basically :

- `ITestContext` represents a `<test>` tag and
- `ISuite` represents a `<suite>` tag

Comment: Thanks Krishnan, that did the job.  I'd been having trouble accessing the ISuite object directly in my before/after tests, did not realize I had to access it from the ITestContext